# Gerrit (rules) Verification: No push without specific user verified

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I am trying to create my prolog rules.pl file to enforce the gating functionality in Gerrit. I need the push to be blocked unless it has a +1 score by a specific user. Here's what I have, but it has some errors which I'm having trouble finding. What changes do I need?

```
submit_rules(S) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(X),
    X =.. [submit | Ls],
    need_specific_approval(Ls,R),
    S =.. [submit| R].    

need_specific_approval(S1, S2) :-
    gerrit:commit_label(label('Verified', 1),need('userA_username_or_email')),
    S2 = [label('UserA-Verified', ok(_)) | S1].
need_specific_approval(S1, [label('UserA-Verified', need(_)) | S1]).
```

Comment: Let me guess: `S =.. [submit, R]` should read `S =.. [submit|R]`

Comment: yes, thanks. I have that in my code, I just typed it incorrectly on here. The problem resides somewhere in 'need_specific_approval." any suggestions? (I have updated my original post)